# Detect changes in an input field in a nested dataTable cell using Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datatables, nested

I have a child dataTable nested in a dataTable. The cells in the child table have input type number fields, I want to detect changes to the field and get the new value. However I am not able to catch the change event.

The input field have a class like such :

```
<td><input type='number' class='edit_detect' name='input_field' value=1</td>
```

I detect changes to the field using the class like this :

```
$(".edit_detect").on('change keyup input', function(event){
    console.log(event);
})
```

But the function never gets run, i.e. the event is never registered.

What do I seem to be doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you load/put your JS link/code at the end of the page (before `</body>`)?

Comment: I am creating the nested table dynamically. Its not on the main html page, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you add element dynamically, you need to bind the event like this:

```
$('body').on('change keyup input', '.edit_detect', function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
```

That way you bound the event called `direct event`. there is also something called `delegate event`, which doesn’t bind the event to the DOM elements, but it delegates the event from their parent. it’s the responsibility of the parent to execute the event on matching child elements. if new child added to parent, parent will take care of executing the event on it.

I used `body` as parent here, but it's better to bind the event to first non-dynamic parent.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise on selection use unique identifier using id attribute in input.

```
<td><input type='number' class='edit_detect' id='input-field' name='input_field' value=1</td>
```

Using id:

```
$("#input_field").change(function(event){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Or using attribute name:

```
$("input[name=input_field]").change(function(event){
        alert($(this).val());
    })
```

Comment: Actually in my code that was intentional, I wanted to detect change in a number of cells in the table, that's why using a class name instead of an unique id.